# Hyperlink not exactly over theorem

Tags: hyperref

Why the hyperlink ("Theorem 0.1" in red) in the pdf generated by the compilation of the following code via PDFLaTeX,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longfbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={Theorem}{theorems}]{theorem}[2][]{
  mystyle,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Theorem~\thetcbcounter~#2,#1}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[label=theo]{}
\lipsum
\end{theorem}
My theorem \Cref{theo}...

\end{document}
```

does not allow to jump exactly over the blue box with Theorem 0.1 when "Theorem 0.1" is clicked? That is, why when "Theorem 0.1" on page 2 is clicked, the blue box in page 1 having Theorem 0.1 does not stay visible? Thanks.

Comment: This code does not compile. We need to know how the assumption environment is defined. Most likely that's the most important part of this issue.

Comment: The environment is "theorem".

Comment: you can raise the anchor by setting e.g. `\def\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{1cm}` before the tcolorbox.

Comment: Ok, and if I'm using additionally another colorboxes in the preamble? E.g. 
```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={proposition}{propositions}]{prop}[2][]{%
breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},title=Proposition~\thetcbcounter~#2,#1}
```
That is, how I can use ```\HyperRaiseLinkDefault``` locally (i.e. only for theorem colorboxes)? Many thanks.